# How to get location accuracy in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to get the location accurate to 50m on android.

```js
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then((resp) => {

     // resp.coords.longitude
          console.log(resp);
          if(resp.coords.accuracy<50)
     {   
                this.loading.hide();
              }
          else{
            alert("The accuracy is "+ resp.coords.accuracy + " m. Location Accuracy is too low. Please Restart your phone.");
             this.loading.hide();
              return false ;     
            }
                 
   }).catch((error) => {

     console.log('Error getting location', error);
  
       });
```

> Here I tried to submit location multiple time always it gives error
>   low accuracy as the location accuracy is 1500m regardless of the fact
>   that  accuracy on android phone is set to **"High Accuracy"**.
>
> No matter how many time I submit the accuracy does not increase until I restart the mobile phone. 
>   Also on the google map the location is incorrect.

How to achieve location precision?
What should be done here in order to get the accurate location without restarting or doing anything as such. The accuracy must be under 100m. Here I am using Ionic Native geolocation PLugin [Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/).

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Are there any other service providing location data other than google Map api?

Comment: Tried to find a solution to same. Multiple times the results are not accurate